# What can I give back to my users for their donations

Tags: website-features

I want to give something back to my users, if they decide to donate to my website.
Everything is free, so I need to give something virtually.

Do you have any ideas?
I thought about postcards (but didn't find api for that).

Comment: You are the best person to decide that. You know your site, we dont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason people donate to websites is because they're already getting something from it, or they expect to.

I don't think you need to worry about it unless you've promised to give something in return. A simple thank you for your donation message would suffice, possibly have a list of donators?